# Problems with Mendeley generated citations

Tags: bibliographies, bugs

I have recently started using Menedely to generate my references which is great because they are generated automatically. However I have recently encountered the following bug that I'm not sure how to fix.
One of my references has been generated in the following manner:

@article{CamAnalysis2,
author = {Korner, T. W.},
file = {:data/thornbill/davenpor/General Notes/Analysis/Analysis 2 Notes Korner.pdf:pdf},=======

It ends as ,======= which is bizarre as it shouldn't and none of the others do. As a result all the references below it in the bibtex file don't work. I can fix it manually but I want to keep using Mendeley to generate my references. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please provide a so-called minimal working example (MWE).  The MWE should contain a compilable code with the minimal code that is necessary in order to reproduce the principal problem. This helps the people here and it will often help the person who asks the question. Currently, the people here have to guess how your code looks.

Comment: Have a look here (http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/13509) how a MWE can look like. **Creating a MWE can easily take an hour.**

Comment: Haven't I included that, my bibtex file just contains: @article{CamAnalysis2, author = {Korner, T. W.}, file = {:data/thornbill/davenpor/General Notes/Analysis/Analysis 2 Notes Korner.pdf:pdf},=======

Comment: Though it has this at the top: Automatically generated by Mendeley Desktop 1.17.9
Any changes to this file will be lost if it is regenerated by Mendeley.

BibTeX export options can be customized via Preferences -> BibTeX in Mendeley Desktop

<<<<<<< HEAD

Comment: Any automated software for generating `.bib` file entries is liable to have issues, the only sure-fire way is to check all generated entries yourself and correct them as necessary.  If it's a replicable issue then you may have a bug which you can report to [Mendeley](http://support.mendeley.com/) otherwise you just have to be careful!